# How to add background shadows for the Stacked bar in High Charts

Tags: highcharts

[image][image]

Just like in the above image, I'm trying to add the background shadows on the bar chart. How can we implement this?

I need bar chart like this can any one help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotBands`:

```
yAxis: {
  plotBands: [{
    from: 0,
    to: 10,
    color: '#828282'
  }, {
    from: 10,
    to: 20,
    color: '#949494'
  }, ...]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4779/

**API Refernece:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands

Comment: thanks for the response. I have modified the question with actual requirement. Please check

Comment: Hi, Ok, so you can use more `plotBands`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4790/

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working as expected but one concern, in the above example chart, on top there is one line is displayed. Need to remove that as well. Can you please provide solution for that as well. Thanks

Comment: We need to cover this line by using `renderer`, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4795/